# Set Header and Footer in a Documnet

Tags: wordml

I have a problem. I need to set following in a Document which is written on **WordML**.

- Set Header and Footer in the document
- Set an Image in the document
- Set a Heading and center it
- So far I have tried out these.

```html
<w:p>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:jc w:val="center"/>
   <w:b w:val="on"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
      <w:t>ABC COMPANY PRIVATE LIMITED</w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:br/>
   <w:r>
   <w:u w:val="single"/>
      <w:t>QUOTA APPLICATION FORM</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

***Thanks In Advance.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an Image to a Document (**WordML**)

```
    <w:pict>
                <w:binData w:name="wordml://02000001.jpg">/9j/4AA..Xof/9k=</w:binData>
                <v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" style="width:100%;height:auto" type="#_x0000_t75">
                  <v:imagedata o:title="network" src="wordml://02000001.jpg"/>
                </v:shape>

   </w:pict>
```

Set a Heading and center it

```
<w:p>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:jc w:val="center"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
      <w:t>Hello, World.</w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:br/>
   <w:r>
      <w:t>How are you, today?</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

For more information regarding **WordML** refer this link.

http://rep.oio.dk/microsoft.com/officeschemas/wordprocessingml_article.htm